# How to find the source of this javascript file?

Tags: google-analytics, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to find which file calls this google analytics js file.

The file is not in the HTML source code. It is either call by a tag management system like GTM or another JS file.

I used chrome developer tools to track it down but not real luck finding it. So far I am thinking it is in the cdn.optimizely.com

Is there something I am missing or a tool that I haven't used yet?[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's being introduced by the GTM container, which can be seen in your screenshot, with the container ID of `GTM-TDDX2G`. If you have access to that container, then you should also be able to see the base/pageview tag which uses the particular tracking ID on that page.

Comment: It is possible if they did it via a Custom HTML tag instead of a Google Analytics tag. I should have access to GTM today to find out. 

However I checked developer tools > Network and I couldnt see that specific GA account attached with GTM.

Another question how can I track the source of a Javascript file in general?

Usually I check network or sources but it doesn't always work